# Upgrading OS, will it keep Android packages?

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10, android-sdk-manager

I have [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) (I don't use it) installed on my Windows 8.1, and I am upgrading my OS to Windows 10. Which folders should I backup to skip downloading the packages from Android SDK Manager in Windows 10?

I don't have knowledge of Android Studio yet, and as it takes lot of time to download those packages, which folders should I backup to skip the fresh downloading again?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your user under the Users in C drive.
2. Go to the location \AppData\Local\Android and backup the entire sdk folder.
   (Note the AppData folder might be hidden).
3. After upgrading, place the backup in exactly the same location as before.

Happy Upgrading! :)